# Query on load/link/initialise phase of java class file

Tags: java, class, reflection

Below is the code:

```
package packagename;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class Super{
    static{
        System.out.println("Super");
    }
    public void superMethod(){

    }
}

class Sub extends Super{
    static{
        System.out.println("Sub");
    }
    public void subMethod(){

    }
}

public class Example {
     static{
        System.out.println("In Example");
      }
     public static void main(String[] args){
        Class myClass = Sub.class;
        Method[] methods = myClass.getMethods();
        for(Method eachMethod :  methods){
            System.out.println(eachMethod.getName() + " with " + eachMethod.getParameterCount() + " parameters");
        }
    }
}
```

On compiling this code and executing,

`> java Example`,

`class Example` gets *loaded*\*linked*\*initialised*. When Java interpreter starts interpreting `main()` method of `class Example`, before evaluating  expression `Sub.class` and assign to `Class myClass` variable, `class Super`& `class Sub` are *loaded* & *linked* but not *initialised*. This is the reason static initialisation blocks of `class Super` & `class Sub` are not executed, as per below output.

```
In Example
subMethod with 0 parameters
superMethod with 0 parameters
wait with 0 parameters
wait with 2 parameters
wait with 1 parameters
equals with 1 parameters
toString with 0 parameters
hashCode with 0 parameters
getClass with 0 parameters
notify with 0 parameters
notifyAll with 0 parameters
```

Is my understanding correct on, load/link/initialise phase of class `Example`, `Super` & `Sub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [JVMS §5.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.5)

> #### 5.5. Initialization
>
> Initialization of a class or interface consists of executing its class or interface initialization method (§2.9).
>
> A class or interface C may be initialized only as a result of:
>
> - The execution of any one of the Java Virtual Machine instructions new, getstatic, putstatic, or invokestatic that references C (§new, §getstatic, §putstatic, §invokestatic). These instructions reference a class or interface directly or indirectly through either a field reference or a method reference.
>
>   Upon execution of a new instruction, the referenced class is initialized if it has not been initialized already.
>
>   Upon execution of a getstatic, putstatic, or invokestatic instruction, the class or interface that declared the resolved field or method is initialized if it has not been initialized already.
> - The first invocation of a java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle instance which was the result of method handle resolution (§5.4.3.5) for a method handle of kind 2 (REF_getStatic), 4 (REF_putStatic), 6 (REF_invokeStatic), or 8 (REF_newInvokeSpecial).
>   *This implies that the class of a bootstrap method is initialized when the bootstrap method is invoked for an invokedynamic instruction (§invokedynamic), as part of the continuing resolution of the call site specifier.*
> - Invocation of certain reflective methods in the class library (§2.12), for example, in class Class or in package java.lang.reflect.
> - If C is a class, the initialization of one of its subclasses.
> - If C is an interface that declares a non-abstract, non-static method, the initialization of a class that implements C directly or indirectly.
> - If C is a class, its designation as the initial class at Java Virtual Machine startup (§5.2).
>
> Prior to initialization, a class or interface must be linked, that is, verified, prepared, and optionally resolved.

Generally, there are specifications for the behavior. If you want to understand the details, you may consider studying [The Java® Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) and [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html) first and come up with questions, if you don’t understand a certain part, then with pointers to the section raising the question.

Answer (score 1):

Only Example is initialized. Class Sub is retrieved from Constant pool

```
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #16.#39        //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Class              #40            //  Sub
```

and relevant code from main

```
Code:
  stack=4, locals=4, args_size=1
     0: ldc_w         #2                  // class Sub
     3: astore_1      
     4: aload_1       
     5: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Class.getMethods:()[Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;
```

So, bytecode confirms your observation that Sub was not initialised. Not required for execution of code.

Comment: when you say: "`Sub` was not initialised. No instance of `Sub` is created in other words.". Does that mean, any class gets initialised only before its instance is about to get created?

Comment: @overexchange looks like it, not required for execution - no initialization. Tested on JDK7 and JDK8

Comment: But, instance of `class Example` did not get created in my above code, But `class Example` passed thru initialisation phase. am not sure, I get you.

Comment: @overexchange Example is initialised, add static like for Sub and it will show. Though instance creation was not required since static method was called. Maybe my instance comment is confusing.

Comment: yes I verified, `Example` is initialised, and query output results says the same, but you did not answer my first comment. I did not get you when you said: "not required for execution - no initialization. " because instance(`new Example()`) of `class Example` is not created in above code.

Comment: @overexchange maybe my instance wording is not best. Rather not required for execution results in not instantiation.

Comment: So, when you say, "Class `Sub` is retrieved from Constant pool", it means Class `Sub` is loaded&linked to JVM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82349/discussion-between-filip-bulovic-and-overexchange).